# How does assignment work in multi-dimensional arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures

```
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int i = 4;
int ia[][][] = new int[i][i=3][i];
System.out.println(ia.length + ", " + ia[0].length + ia[0][0].length);
}
}
```

I would have thougth that 3, 4, 3 would have been printed instead of the valid answer: "4, 3, 3".
The variable ia has 3 arrays, so why is ia.length not 3?

Answer (score 1):

Length is 4 because you're initializing i to 4 in the line before inizializing the array.

So replacing i with actual values you're doing

```
int ia[][][] = new int[4][3][3];
```

Also, i'd consider assigning i a new value at the same time as initializing the array to be bad practice (readability).

Furhthermore, ia doesn't "have 3 arrays" it's a three-dimensinal array.

Comment: but ia[0] should be 4 right? it prints 3. could u please explain why?

Comment: Well no, ia[0] contains an int[3][3] in your example, thus lenght 3

Comment: `i` has length 4.  Each of those four elements is an `int[3][3]` -- that's an array of length 3, and each of *those* is an array of length 3.  `i[0], i[1], i[2], and i[3]` are each of length 3.  Going down one level, each of their elements (such as `i[2][0]`) has a length of 3.

Answer (score 1):

According to [15.10.2. Run-Time Evaluation of Array Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1)

> First, the dimension expressions are evaluated, left-to-right. If any of the expression evaluations completes abruptly, the expressions to the right of it are not evaluated.

This is a simple case with no exceptions, only the left-to-right part of rule applies. So to evaluate `new int[i][i=3][i]`, the following steps happen:

1. Evaluate `i` (resulting in 4)
2. Evaluate `i=3` (setting `i` to 3 and resulting in 3)
3. Evaluate `i` (resulting in 3 since the previous step set it to 3)

The dimensions with which the array is creates are therefore 4, 3, 3.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that but I am still confused about why ia[0].length prints 3 and not 4. Please explains that to me.

Comment: @ShahidSarwar 4 is the length of `ia` itself. There is only one 4 here, everything else is 3.